# Bootstrap 4 not loaded when publishing Core MVC site to Azure

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-4

I have a Core MVC application (.NETCoreApp 1.1) which I upgraded from bootstrap 3.3.7 to 4.0 (via Bower).

Everything renders as expected locally, but when publishing to Azure it goes wrong, on the server bootstrap 4 is not applied, the site is not rendered correctly.

With the Chrome developer tools I can see that locally the bootstrap 4 css is loaded correctly from the lib folder, on the server I don't even see a lib folder.
I tried a lot, I even deleted all files on the server and published the site again, with the same result.

This is bugging me for hours, can somebody help me?

**Edit 28/01/2018 21:21**
On the server I can see bootstrap 3.3.7 is still loaded via aspnetcdn.com

[image]

Comment: did you change the conditional in the `_layout.chstml` for Staged, Production to point to 4.0 cdn

Comment: You helped me a lot, I started from the default vs template that used the cdn and had the local bootstrap css as fallback.  The cdn url wasn't of course updated with the bootstrap upgrade, this is also the case for the js files.  Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you change the conditional in the _layout.chstml for Staged, Production to point to 4.0 cdn

since publishing usually results in a "release" non-development build it sets the environment to production or staged.  the conditional will default to what ever is set there.